# Camel: doTry in the Choice clause

Tags: java, apache-camel

Colleagues, I'am trying to configure Camel route with `choice` and `doTry`.
My problem is `Cannot resolve method 'when'` on the second `when` clause.
The question: is it possible to use `doTry` construction in `choice` clause?

The route looks like:

```
public void configure() {
        from("sftp://.....").choice()
            .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML P")).log("Validate ${file:name}").bean(new MessProcessor(), "logInputMessDetails")
             .doTry().
                    to("validator:file:C:\\Users...\\xsds\\p.xsd").log("${file:name} is valid")
             .doCatch(ValidationException.class)
                 .log("XML P is not valid")
                 .to("file:sftp-inbound\\data-invalid\\" + header("CamelFileParent").toString())
                 .bean(messProcessor, "stopCamel")
/*The problem is here*/ .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML X")).log("Validate ${file:name}").bean(new MessProcessor(), "logInputMessDetails").
            doTry().to("validator:file:C:\\Users\....\xsds\\position.xsd").log("${file:name} is valid").
            doCatch(ValidationException.class).log("XML X is not valid").to("file:sftp-inbound\\data-invalid\\" + header("CamelFileParent").toString()).
            bean(messProcessor, "stopCamel")
            .end();

    }
```

**UPDATE**

Route after `.bean(messProcessor, "stopCamel")` deleting:

```
public void configure() {
        from("sftp://.....").choice()
            .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML P")).log("Validate ${file:name}").bean(new MessProcessor(), "logInputMessDetails")
             .doTry().
                    to("validator:file:C:\\Users...\\xsds\\p.xsd").log("${file:name} is valid")
             .doCatch(ValidationException.class)
                 .log("XML P is not valid")
                 .to("file:sftp-inbound\\data-invalid\\" + header("CamelFileParent").toString())
                 .end;
/*The problem is still here*/ .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML X")).log("Validate ${file:name}").bean(new MessProcessor(), "logInputMessDetails").
            doTry().to("validator:file:C:\\Users\....\xsds\\position.xsd").log("${file:name} is valid").
            doCatch(ValidationException.class).log("XML X is not valid").to("file:sftp-inbound\\data-invalid\\" + header("CamelFileParent").toString()).
            bean(messProcessor, "stopCamel")
            .end();

    }
```

**UPDATE**
One more variant

```
public void configure() {

        from("sftp:...}")

                .choice()
                .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML_POS")).log("Validate ${file:name}")
                .to("validator:file:C:\\pos.xsd").log("${file:name} valid")
                .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("XML_SETS")).log("Validate ${file:name}")
                 .to("validator:file:C:\\sets.xsd").log("${file:name} valid").end()
               .onException(Exception.class)
               .process(new FailureResponseProcessor())
               .handled(true);

            /*to("file:sftp-inbound");*/
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the error handling from the route,

```
 onException (exception)
   handled (true)
   process failure processor
```

And then just have the route

```
from ftp
 to validate
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is probably that

```
.bean(messProcessor, "stopCamel")
```

does not result in an object that support the `when()` method.

Keep in mind: this is still ordinary Java. You can only call those methods on an object that the corresponding class defines. And the compiler just tells you that calling `bean()` does result in something that does not know `when`.

So the answer is to step back and look into the exact result type of `bean()` and probably make a different call there.

Comment: i removed `bean` but nothing changes.

Comment: The answer is not to blindly play around with those calls! The answer is to step back and to **learn** what those methods mean and do. To then understand how to achieve the desired result!

Comment: ChostCat, do you reccomend to use `.multicast().parallelProcessing()` in my case? I need to validate xml and then, if every xml is valid, upload it into db.

Comment: That sounds like an valid idea.

Comment: Quite diificult... I can't configure the route: i just need to validate xmls, stop process if any is not valid...ufff. i will be glad for any help.